# How to stop Spacemacs from overriding the clipboard and enabling pasting on search at the same time?

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I often do the following things:

1. Copy text outside emacs
2. Switch back to emacs, delete some text
3. Paste

The problem is that I get back the deleted text since it overwrites the clipboard. To solve this problem, I added the following code in `~/.spacemacs`

```lisp
(defun dotspacemacs/user-config ()
  (setq x-select-enable-clipboard nil)
  (define-key evil-visual-state-map (kbd "s-c") (kbd "\"+y"))
  (define-key evil-insert-state-map  (kbd "s-v") (kbd "^R+"))
  (define-key evil-ex-completion-map (kbd "s-v") (kbd "^R+"))
  (define-key evil-ex-search-keymap  (kbd "s-v") (kbd "^R+")))
```

Now the problem has gone, but I encountered a new problem because of those lines: I cannot paste text from the clipboard when pressing `C-s RET` to search for words. When I press `Cmd + V`(I use macOS) after pressing `C-s RET`, I got text copied from Emacs instead of from the clipboard. How to solve that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Just use `q /` to search for texts. I can paste in it.